# Forms Authentication across virtual directories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am trying to share forms auth from a root application to a sub application running in a virtual directory. I am having trouble with authentication in the subsite.

In the parent application everything works as expected.

I have the following setup:

Parent application:

- **URL**: `http://localhost:1336/`
- `<forms loginUrl="~/account/sign-in" protection="All" timeout="30" name=".MYAPPLICATION" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="/" />`

Virtual Directory:

- **URL**: `http://localhost:1336/subsite`
- `<forms loginUrl="/account/sign-in" protection="All" timeout="30" name=".MYAPPLICATION" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" defaultUrl="/" />`

When i try to a `http://localhost:1336/subsite` I get the following flow:

- **GET** for `http://localhost:1336/subsite` -> 302 to /account/sign-in?ReturnUrl=%2fsubsite *(looks ok)*
- Enter User/password
- **POST** to `http://localhost:1336/account/sign-in?ReturnUrl=%2fsubsite` -> 302 /subsite *(great the auth looks like its successful)*
- **GET** for `http://localhost:1336/subsite` -> 302 to /account/sign-in?ReturnUrl=%2fsubsite *(IE the subsite doesnt think its authenticated)*

Also i can see the cookie in the list in my browser (so its actually there)

What have I got wrong in my config that's stopping my subsite from sharing the parent cookie?

I am running this on IISExpress

Comment: have you set a common machineKey in web.config?

Comment: @davea my understanding is that this is only required if the sites are on different physical machines. These are both on my dev box. Is this not the case?

Comment: I don't think that's true. I'm working on a project where the opposite is true. 1 host, main and sub-domain (admin and client) and we DONT respect sign-ons to keep division. We did not have to configure this behavior. It was default. Ergo, I assume that hosting from same machine does not make a difference.

Comment: @davea Ok cool, ill give that a crack :)

Comment: Also interested in this.

Comment: @davea yeah that sorted it out, Thanks. You should post it as an answer so i can mark it :). It looks like a fail in my understanding of what a machinekey does. I used     <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate"
            decryptionKey="AutoGenerate"
            validation="SHA1"/>

Comment: will do. glad to finally pay back previous help. As for misunderstanding, the name is outright misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your web.config files, set a common machine key between the projects so that the 2 domains share validation and decryption keys.

example:

```
<machineKey validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69BBAAD8402ABD2EE0B667A8B44EA7DD4374267A75D7" 
decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D217CECFFB9628809BDB8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, just as a FYI i used `validationKey="AutoGenerate" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate"` to avoid needing to generate the keys myself. This seems to work well on the same machine (but i assume might fail when across different machines)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Agreed, that should be mentioned. I'm going to come back to this and clean up my answer when I have time.