# SQL Server stored proc slowing down queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, transactions

8/19/2014 - This question is still open. It seems now this is happening even though I have not run the stored procedure. I don't have enough experience yet to know what kinds of things will cause a SQL server to have slow downs like this.

---

I have a problem that seems weird to me. Two things that seem unrelated have correlated twice now.

First, I have a stored procedure in ***SQL Server 2008 Express R2*** that is wrapped in a transaction (code below). Inside the transaction,

- records older than a certain date are being copied from a log table into a log archive table.
- then the records are deleted from the log table.

The database is on a dedicated hosting server.

Second, I have a website page that loads three ***HTML*** tables via ***AJAX***. The code behind is reading from the same database that the Log tables are on, but none of the DB tables overlap. The queries are executed via ***LINQ-to-Entities*** using ***Entity Framework*** 6. They are somewhat complex queries, but under normal circumstances, each of the HTML tables take less than 5 seconds to load once the ***AJAX*** call is kicked off. The website is on a shared hosting server.

**NO OTHER QUERIES ON THE SITE ARE SLOW. Only these 2.**

For some reason, after I execute the stored procedure, the ***AJAX*** queries on the webpage run so long that they timeout and no data loads. I had to open the timeout window to 180 seconds for them to even have a chance to load before timeout.

The only way I am able to get the queries back to "normal" speed is to STOP the ***SQL Server service***, and START it again. After, the webpage loads quickly.

My concern is that the stored procedure that I created is causing something to get hung up in the ***SQL Server***, or memory issues, or something.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
USE [Main]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Jason Watts
-- Create date: 7/30/2014
-- Description: Archives every record in ErrorLogs 
--              older than 2 months into the 
--              ErroLogsArchive table.
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ArchiveErrorLogs] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Init variables and error code
    Declare @TransactionCountOnEntry int;
    Declare @ErrorCode int;
    Select @ErrorCode = @@Error;

    -- Begin transaction processing for rollback option
    If @ErrorCode = 0
    Begin
       Select @TransactionCountOnEntry = @@TranCount;
       BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    End

    -- Get the current date/time
    Declare @ArchiveDT datetime;
    SELECT @ArchiveDT = DATEADD(m, -2, GETDATE());

    -- Copy the records from ErrorLogs to ErrorLogsArchive
    If @ErrorCode = 0
    Begin
        INSERT INTO ErrorLogsArchive (Area,Library,Method,ErrorLevel,[Message],Stacktrace,LogDate)
        SELECT Area,Library,Method,ErrorLevel,[Message],Stacktrace,LogDate
        FROM ErrorLogs
        WHERE LogDate <= @ArchiveDT;

        Select @ErrorCode = @@ERROR;
    End

    -- Delete the records from ErrorLogs
    If @ErrorCode = 0
    Begin
        DELETE FROM ErrorLogs
        WHERE LogDate <= @ArchiveDT;

        Select @ErrorCode = @@ERROR;
    End

    -- End the transaction
    If @@TranCount > @TransactionCountOnEntry
    Begin
       If @ErrorCode = 0
          COMMIT TRANSACTION;
       Else
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    End

    -- Return
    Return @ErrorCode;
END
```

The original log table had 1.5 million records before I ran the procedure this morning. On the first go I was moving where older than 3 months, and it moved 700,000 records successfully. Though it took about 5 1/2 minutes to run. Then I bumped it down to 2 months, and it moved another 200,000 records in about 1 1/2 minutes.

After each run, the webpage table loads slowed to a crawl, then returned to normal after restarting the SQL Server service. I don't understand what could be causing the slow down. If it had not happened twice, I would not have thought them to be related.

*update*

As I mentioned above, the same 2 queries are now running slow and I have not performed the archive function. I feel that there is some simple issue here, I just don't know what it could be.

Comment: There are lots of places where the real problem can hide. I can only suggest a few places based on my experience: (1) log file size can grow big after a big insert/delete. Increase the log's file size or ship to to another location, (2) memory: in its default config, SQL Server can eat up all the system's memory. Check your RAM after the archive operations.

Comment: The log file is fairly large. The database is 3GB, and the log is 12GB. Should I do something about the log file? Again, after restart of the server service, everything runs normal even with the large log file.

Comment: As to the RAM, the system has 8GB. System RAM usage after the operation jumped from ~2.7GB to ~3.8GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Ghost Cleanup** is causing your slow performance.

Read up on **[Ghost cleanup in depth](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-ghost-cleanup-in-depth/)**

In short, **delete operations do NOT delete/remove rows**. The "deleted" rows are marked for deletion, and then (gradually), the "memory" is reallocated 1-10 pages at a time. This is an "optimization" of SQL Server.

---

### **Execution Plan**

This antiquated garbage collecting is complicated further by the presence of an **[Execution Plan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx)** (*read up*) which tries to "hold on" to the deleted rows. The result is problematic **Cluster F** that resembles, but isn't quit, a dead-lock.

you can delete an execution plan using **[DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283(v=sql.105).aspx)**

---

### **Known Error in Ghosting Cleanup:**

To make matters worse, there is a known bug with SQL Server failing to properly handle Ghosted Records in the Millions

[ghost_record_count values keep increasing in SQL Server 2008 R2 or in SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2622823)

---

### **Restarting SQL Server:**

I suspect that, in addition to flushing all Execution Plans, a newly started ***SQL Server*** places higher importance on immediate "cleanup" of ghost images.

---

### Followup

From SQLMag, [When a Delete isn’t Really a Delete](http://sqlmag.com/blog/when-delete-isn-t-really-delete)

> So when do the deleted records get removed? The act of deleting a record doesn’t put that record on the queue of work for the ghost cleanup task. It’s not until the database page on which the deleted record resides is read again by the SQL Server Storage Engine that the page will be queued up for definite ghost record removal.
>   The ghost cleanup task will look at its queue of things to do, and if it is empty, it will process part of a database on an instance to see if the database has ghost records to be removed. The only way to make sure that the space used by a ghost record is freed up quickly is to do something such as a table scan or an index rebuild so that all pages in the table are accessed by the Storage Engine and ghost records are queued for removal.

- Seems the tables affected were on same "page" as log table.
- I gather from this, that there are options. A table scan may help.

Comment: DaveA, thank you for this through response. The part that has baffled me the most is why these two AJAX calls are slow. On the page that they are on, I am loading 3 Kendo Grids via AJAX. 1 and 2 are slow. 3 loads instantly. If I go to any other page, the tables there load immediately. So it is only these two AJAX loads. Further, these slow queries have no overlapping tables with the one affected by the stored proc.

Comment: Based on the information above it looks like my options are limited. As I see it, I can A) Disable ghost cleanup, but then I would need to re-index the table, B) Restart the server everytime.

Comment: Speaking of restarting the server, after the restart, if I refresh the page with the slow queries, the first time I refresh they load slow again. Then every subsequent time they load in 1 or 2 seconds. That is until whatever this is happens again and slows them down.

Comment: DaveA, is there any operation that you know of, such as a move, or a drop, or anything that would be a way to accomplish the same task but side step the ghost cleanup? I mean, is this a problem that DBA's on large systems just have to deal with? "Nature of the beast" as it were?

Comment: @jwatts1980, I'm also mystified why ghosting affects some tables and not others. Could be just tables that are replicated, could be almost anything.

Comment: @jwatts1980 As for workarounds, I haven't found anything obvious. Hardcore DBA's (something neither of us wants to be) are kvetching about this. If you were able to copy all logged files and truncate the original table, you would probably side step the issue.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Another possibility is to delete the Execution Plan. The syntax is available in the link in my post. You would have to dig around for many of the specifics params that identify that Execution Plan. But short of truncating, I've found no way to delete records w/o ghosting :\   Will look around some more...

Comment: DaveA, I'm marking this as the answer. If this isn't the issue, then I don't even know how to ask the right question. SO won't let me award the bounty for 24 hours. But it will be yours.

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on this problem!

Comment: @jwatts1980, keep it open and we'll keep trying. I'm not just in this for bounty points. Let's see if we can work through this. I hope I've given you some ideas to try

Comment: Sounds good, DaveA. Ha! I just realized that you're the same guy that helped me on my last SQL issue for which I awarded you a bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255011/how-to-store-sessionstate-in-database-for-a-hosted-net-mvc-website